# Design Api for Export and Abort export

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, oop

I am creating an API to support Export and abort operation . For eg

```
    class Export
    {
        //starts an export operation.
        void Start();
        //aborts an export operation
        void Abort();
    }
```

The clients can be Gui or non-Gui applications. The Start operation can take some time to do its job and in between users can call abort.
So how can the api looks like i.e return value of these methods ?
Should Start implementation needs the operation to be started in new thread and return immediately or should it be synchronous ?

Hint : the start operation will do n jobs and if a job ( x where x < n) gets started then calling abort should wait (not sure whether waiting is good here , which is also a discussion point here) till the xth job gets completed  and should not start with x+1 th operation.

Hence when an abort gets called should it return immediately or how it should be ?

Right now how i have made is ,

Start --> to be synchronous.
When abort is called it will wait till the start complete with the current operation and return then abort method will return . But somehow i get a feeling that what i am doing is wrong.

Any help is appreciated , Thanks in advance .

Note: I have also thought about keeping both the methods as asynchronous and notifying the clients about the completion with events saying Start completed , Abort completed.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx) and declare your export method with a [`CancellationToken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.aspx) argument.

```
Task ExportAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
```

To cancel the operation, simply call [`Cancel()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.cancel.aspx) on the [`CancellationTokenSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.aspx) you used to create the `CancellationToken` you passed in the call.

Comment: Good to know about different asynchronous patterns , Thanks :)

Comment: If i need to have Only Export and Abort then it (TAP) will be the best approach to follow , but what if i wanted to extend this Interface with Pause and continue operation . DO you still feel we can have the extension with TAP approach ?